# Multi-column lineplot using matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

a total inexpert here trying to learn.I want to make a multi-line graph using matplotlib or seaborn where the data is grouped as follows:

```
    X1 X2 X3
0   10 20 30
1   0  16 40
2   10 60 80
3   20 20 90
```

The idea is to plot the three points and have them connected by a line, being the x-axis equal to X1, X2, X3 (column labels) and the y-axis as the row values. I couldn't find any answer to this problem anywhere. Thank you very much in advance for the answers!

Comment: Is your data a pandas DataFrame? A CSV file?

Comment: You said **three points**, what are they from your sample data?

Comment: Yes it is a dataframe, and the three points correspond to the three values by each row, e.g. first point (X1,10), second (X2,20), third (X3,30).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
df.T.plot()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @SEBASTIAN you're welcome. If it helps, please consider upvote/accept the answer.